# how to view excel file in browser using jsp

Tags: java, excel, jsp

I have an excel file and wanted to display the same in a jsp page. Im using the below code to display the same

```
  <% 
  response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
  response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment;filename=Data.xlsx")%>
```

When I try to click the jsp link,the excel sheet gets downloaded automatically.  But I want the excel sheet to be displayed on the browser in the jsp page.

Any help on the above is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

for me you should Stream your file into the response from the servlet, something like this :

```
transfert(yourFile.getInputStream(),response.getOutputStream(), true);

public static void transfert(InputStream in , OutputStream out, boolean closeOnExit ) throws Exception{
try{byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    int n;
    while((n=in.read(buf))!=-1){
        out.write(buf,0,n);
        out.flush();}  
   }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be two approaches.

- If you don't have any problem in hosting excel file using 3rd party services like google docs or MS OneDrive, then you can upload your files there and use `embedded html` code generated by those services.
- Another alternative is to process excel file using some libraries like `apache-poi` and render it on jsp page.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have used apache-poi and was able to get the input stream object of the corresponding worksheet. Not sure how to pass the content and display in the jsp. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any framework? Normally how do you pass data from controller to view?

Comment: Im not using any framework, For the other pages, when the request is invoked, the request is sent to the server for processing, the application process the request and returns the response in the form of a string and I use the jsp response objects to write the string back to the jsp.

Comment: @vr3w3c9 How do you write server side code? Is it also in jsp file?

Comment: No I have java classes, Bussiness layer classes & they connect to DAO layer process the request and send the response string back to the jsp.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to achieve this. But you can generate `html` code for displaying your data on server and then pass that to jsp page by setting content type as `text/html`.

Answer (score 0):

i am using following code to display excel file in jsp page

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Excel Web View</title>

<%@ page import="java.io.FileInputStream" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*" %>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*"%>
</head>
<body>

<table border="1">

<%

 String filename="C:\\Users\\User01\\Desktop\\hello.xls"
 String extension = "";

 int i = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
 if (i >= 0) {
     extension = filename.substring(i+1);
 }

 if(extension !=null && extension.contains("xlsx"))
  {

    if(filename != null && !filename.equals("")){
        try{

            FileInputStream fs =new FileInputStream(filename);
            XSSFWorkbook  wb = new XSSFWorkbook (fs);
            for(int k = 0; k < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); k++){
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k);
            int rows  = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
            DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

            for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
            XSSFRow row   = sheet.getRow(r);

            int cells = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); 
            %><tr><%
            for(int n=0;n<cells;n++)
            {
              %><td><%
           =formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(n))
             %></td><%
            }
           %></tr><%
            }
            }
            }
           catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
           }
           }
           }
         else {
           if(filename != null && !filename.equals("")){
           try{
                FileInputStream fs =new FileInputStream(filename);
                HSSFWorkbook  wb = new HSSFWorkbook (fs);
                for(int k = 0; k < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); k++){
                HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k);
                int rows  = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
                DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

                for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
                    HSSFRow row   = sheet.getRow(r);
                    int cells = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); 
                %><tr><%
                    for(int n=0;n<cells;n++){
                %><td><%
                =formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(n))
                %></td><%
                }
                %></tr><%
                }
                }
                }
                 catch(Exception e){
                 System.out.println(e);
                 }
                 }
                 }
               %>
         </table>
         </body>
         </html>
```

and add Dependency in pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
   <version>3.16</version>
</dependency>
```